# What is instantiated when calling base constructor

Tags: c#

Suppose I have this code

```
class administrator: uzivatel
{
    public administrator(string jmeno,string prijmeni) : base(jmeno,prijmeni) { }

    public string Jmeno
    {
        get { return base.jmeno; }
    }
}
```

Class `administrator` inherits from class `uzivatel` and calls base constructor which instantiates the variable `jmeno` and variable `prijmeni`.

Those variables are inherited from parent class. The property `jmeno` will return `this.jmeno`, which I understand, but it can also can return the value of `base.jmeno`.

How is possible to return `base.jmeno` when there is no created object of class `uzivatel`?

Comment: _Class uzivatel inherits from class administrator_ No. administrator inherits uzivatel.

Comment: *"How is possible to return base.jmeno, when there is no created object of class uzivatel"* `Administrator` is an object of class `uzivatel`, so base just refers to the inherited portions of `uzivatel`. Its returning a property value, not `uzivatel`.

Comment: @JabBohac how come you don't refer to the [MSDN C# Reference `base`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx)

Comment: Why the down vote? Any specific reason? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to learn a bit more about how inheritance and how it works.

The reason why this works is because an `administrator` object **IS A** `uzivatel` object!  This means when you instantiate `adminstrator` with a constructor that calls upon the base class, then the constructor for the base class is also called.  This allows the other variables to be initialized.

You also mention

> The property jmeno will return this.jmeno, which I understand, but it can also can return the value of base.jmeno.

Not exactly.  In this situation `base.jmeno == this.jmeno` because as stated earlier your `administrator` object *IS A* `uzivatel` object.  Remember inheritance means the subclass inherits all of the properties, fields, and methods of its superclass.